# Instalación prestashop 1.7.x que no termina nunca

Tags: prestashop, prestashop1.7, instalacion

Llevo un par de días intentando instalar cualquiera de las versiones 1.7.x en un *VPS* con una instalación limpia de *Debian GNU/Linux 8.10* (jessie).

Se crea el usuario FTP y se instala *VESTACP* y todo estupendo, subo por FTP los ficheros y al entrar por url al dominio se abre el instalador, descomprime sus ficheros, pide los datos de la nueva tienda y sus conexiones a la base de datos y todo parece que va bien hasta llegar al último paso, donde debería aparecer la famosa barra de progreso y la lista de las tareas que está haciendo, pero en mi caso no aparece. Por código veo que sí está, pero aparece con "`display:none`", y aunque la haga visible, obviamente no funciona.

---

***Error instalación prestashop 1.7.x ultimo paso sin barra de progreso***

[image: Error instalación prestashop 1.7.x ultimo paso sin barra de progreso]

---

Es como si el disparador que provoca el inicio de la instalación no se disparara (valga la redundancia).

También he visto que por lo que parece, no carga Jquery, aunque en el primero de los pasos tampoco lo carga y me deja llegar al último de los pasos.

***Error instalacion prestashop 1.7.x***

---

[image: Error instalacion prestashop 1.7.x]

---

Total, que no sé por donde tirar ya...

Comment: no has checado el log de errores tanto del servidor como de PHP ?

Comment: Sí que revisé la carpeta de logs, tanto del VPS como de php en concreto, y no hay errores más allá de los típicos y comunes que ya conocía. Nada relativo al prestashop ni a no llegar a Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error 500, es muy probable que el problema sea por permisos de archivo, lo que debes hacer es cambiar todos los archivos de forma recursiva a `0644` y las carpetas a `0755`, esto lo puedes conseguir con FileZilla.

Comment: El error 500 es al llegar a jquery, que sin embargo sí está "físicamente" en la ruta donde ahí dice que no lo encuentra. Todos los permisos, tanto de archivos desde la raíz, como las carpetas y sus subcarpetas están puestos a 0777 porque también pensé en ello, pero no me lo solucionó tampoco :(

Comment: En la mayoria de servidores 0777 te dara problemas, desde luego que todo depende del servidor, pero los permisos habituales deben ser como te mencione, `0755` para carpetas y `0644` para archivos.

Comment: Vaya, pues entonces hay algo que yo desconocía el funcionamiento. Resulta que poniéndolo tal como dices sí ha funcionado y la instalación sigue su curso sin dar problema. Mil gracias @Rolige